# How to deal with long-running tests in MSTest

Tags: .net, resharper, mstest

I've got a few tests using the MSTest framework which are very long running. These tests are valuable, and I sometimes run them manually. But when I simply want to run "all tests" I want to exclude them by default. I'm using the Resharper test runner to run tests.

When I mark test test as `[Ignored]` then I can't run it anymore, not even when directly selected.

How can I approach this in a good way?

Answer (score 4):

In my point of view, this is a good point to use [`TestCategoryAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).

Just mark your long-running test:

```
[TestCategory("LongRunningTest")]
[TestMethod]
public void LongRunningTest()
{
    // test
}
```

And then you can parametrize the execution of the MSTest on your build server. Just use [the command line parameter](https://hub.packtpub.com/command-line/) `/category:!LongRunningTest` for the build, where you want to skip long-running tests.

You can view categories in VisualStudion as well. Just go to Test Explorer and group tests by Traits:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any built-in way how to accomplish that with MSTest. But I see some alternatives:

1. Use a dedicated MSTest project (e. g. `LongRunningTests`) → you can run these tests manually on demand, on your CI environment, etc.
2. Switch over to NUnit and use the [`Explicit` attribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/explicit.html).
3. Create your own `LongRunningTest` attribute within MSTest and exclude this category within the UI.
4. Create another build configuration (e. g. `Release`, `Debug` and `LoadTest`) and work with preprocessor directives:

```cs
#if !LoadTest
[Ignored]
#endif
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    // the usual AAA stuff
}
```